# Popover crashes with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *Button;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPopoverController *poc;


@end
```

this is what i declared in interface file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.Button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_Button addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(showPop:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.Button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    self.Button.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

   [self.view addSubview:self.Button];

   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)showPop:(UIButton *)button {
    UIViewController *detailsViewController =[[UIViewController alloc] init];

    self.poc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:detailsViewController];
    [self.poc setDelegate:self];
    [self.poc presentPopoverFromRect:_Button.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```

crashes on`[self.poc setdelegate:self]`with 
errorlibc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

green color on this line of code with thread SIGABRT.
i have run this in ipad but still app crashes with the same error.
`

Comment: why is your `poc` property marked `retain` as opposed to `strong`?

Comment: strong and retain both does the same work i think

Comment: Show the whole error message. There should be more after "exception of type NSException". `IBOutlet` should be `weak`, but it's doesn't seems to be really a `IBOutlet` in your case. Also, var should start with a lowercase (`button` instead of `Button`).